# yii2-advanced modal conflict with adminlte

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I just want to get your opinion regarding my problem.
Currently, I'm developing a system using Yii2 Advanced.AdminLte is used for the backend.
Everything went well until I used modal on my page. I noticed that user account dropdown didn't work.

What should I do with? Should I have to debug everything?

Below is the screenshot when I'm not using modal on my page.

[image]

Comment: What answer are you expecting here exactly? "Should I debug?" Well yeah, you should...

Comment: what i mean is that. if ever you'd encounter this problem please help me. I'm new with this php framework.

Comment: Before people unvote for your post, please remove from here.